# Can two "using" collide?

Tags: c++

So I have to use some members of Boost library and some from the std namespace. Right now, I have `using boost::asio::ip::tcp;` declared and am calling appropriate members with `std::` and for example `tcp::iostream server()`. Is there any reason why I shouldn't add another `using`, namely `using namespace std;` and then call all the `std` things without `std::` prefix? Can these two somehow collide or cause malfunction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that it is usually considered a bad practice to have `using` directives that import names from the `std` namespace (especially when at namespace scope and/or in a header file), because it easily leads to name clashes, consider the following program:

```
namespace A { void foo() { } }
namespace B { void foo() { } }

int main()
{
    using namespace A;
    using namespace B;
    foo();
}
```

How should the compiler resolve the call to `foo()`? Well, it won't. It is ambiguous, because both `A::foo()` and `B:foo()` can now be referred to as the unqualified `foo()`.

If there are entities with the same name in the `std` namespace and in the global namespace (or in any other namespace for which you have a `using` directive), ambiguities due to name clashes are likely to arise.

In your specific case, a `using` directive such as:

```
using namespace std;
```

Will be unlikely to clash with the name `tcp` introduced by your `using` *declaration* (notice, that a `using` declaration imports just one specific name and is, therefore, preferable).

Yet, it is still considered to be poor programming style and you should not do it, regardless of whether you have some other `using` directive or `using` declaration already in place.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can. The compiler can't resolve the correct namespace in that case. The solution is to use prefixes (for example `std::`).

You can also put the `using namespace` keywords inside a function or other block, so the namespace won't be used outside it:

```
void foo()
{
    using namespace ns;
} // ns won't be used after this
```

Furthermore, namespace usage can be limited to a header:

```
namespace ns
{
    #include "ns.h"
}
```

However, limiting the namespace to a header is *not* recommended because it causes problems in many cases.

Comment: You can't `#undef` a namespace. Once you've pulled it in, it's in. The names are scoped, however, so a using directive within a scope only introduces names into that scope.

Comment: @PeteBecker OK, I removed the part about `#undef`.

Comment: +1 for to the point answer first and then advising about recommended practises rather than rambling on from the go :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do a good job of explaining how ambiguities can be resolved when you have two or more `using namespace` *directives*, but it's worth pointing out that the situation is different if you have `using` *declarations* that pull in two or more specific names from within namespaces, like this:

```
namespace A { void foo() { } }
namespace B { void foo() { } }

int main()
{
    using A::foo;
    using B::foo;
    return 0;
}
```

The above is always a compile error, even though neither `foo` is ever used. This is because `using` *declarations*, as the name suggests, actually *declare* a name in their enclosing scope to be an alias to a name in some other namespace. This is in contrast to a `using namespace` *directive*, which merely *makes names available* in their enclosing scope without actually declaring any new names.

If you really want to, it's possible to resolve the above code like this:

```
using fooa = A::foo;
using foob = B::foo;
```

But `using` *declarations* should usually be avoided anyway, because they have some other semantic surprises which can bite you in unexpected, subtle, and sometimes undetectable ways. The exception is `using` a base class member within a derived class, which is usually OK, though not often necessary.